# Как исправить? TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, type-error

Не очень понимаю, в чем ошибка (TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable), вроде все типы данных соответствуют операциям.

**Задача:**
Дан двумерный массив и два числа: i и j. Поменяйте в массиве столбцы с номерами i и j.

**Входные данные:**
Программа получает на вход в первой строке размеры массива n≤100 и m≤100, затем элементы массива, а в последней строке числа i и j.

**Выходные данные:**
Выведите полученный массив.

Вот код:

```
n, m = map(int,input().split())
a = [list(map(int,input().split())) for i in range(n)]
n1, m1 = map(int,input().split())
b = [0] * m
for i in range (m):
    a[n1][i] = b[0][i]
    a[n1][i] = a[m1][i]
    a[m1][i] = b[0][i]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        ptint(a[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас b - это одномерный список. А обращаетесь вы к нему как к списку списков.

```
>>> b = [0] * 10
>>> b[0][5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
>>> b
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Спасибо, поправил еще немного код и теперь всё работает как надо